# NET 5 api application doesn't stay open on other computer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have built a NET 5 api application which works fine on my devPC. When it starts, it opens a command window and displays the uri and port the application is hosted on and I'm able to test it using Postman and Swagger.
[image]

Problem is when share the .exe file or even the entire folder with all dependencies with a clientPC, they are not able to access it. More accurately, the command window opens and closes immediately.

On the properties I have double checked and it is definitely set to .NET 5.0
[image]

Here is the dotnet info from the clientPC. The runtime is definitely installed and I have also added the 5.0.7 version afterwards just incase. Also restarted the clientPC after install.
[image]

When I run it in the clientPC from command line, a separate window opens and closes almost immediately, there isn't even a log created. On the devPC when started from command line or directly from .exe file the other window which opens, stays open as show in the first image.

This is my first NET 5 application so I might be missing some basic information. Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Open it from a command line to see if it's outputting anything. Do they have the .NET 5 runtime installed? It won't run without it

Comment: This answer is lacking in any relevant troubleshooting information.

Comment: Add logging to your application and log to a file. The default Web API template only logs to the console, which means that once the console is closed any errors are lost.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the runtime I installed was x64 and my application was configured to x86. I had doubts that it was something simple.

Anyways thank you for the helpful suggestions guys.